Not getting an update with callback_query when user presses an inline button (Telegram webhook)
Using node-telegram-bot-api. I have a Webhook that works properly - i get updates when messages are sent, but no update is sent when the user presses a button in an inline keyboard.
class BotController {
    async handleUpdate(req, res, next){
        console.log(req.body);

        if (req.body.message.text === "/getTypes"){
            sendTypesKeyboard(req.body.message.chat.id);
        }
        return res.json({message: "update handled"});
    }    
}

const sendTypesKeyboard = async (chatId) => {
    const types = await typeDbHandler.getAll();
    const options = {
        reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
            inline_keyboard: types.map((type) => 
                [{"text": type.name, "callback_data": type.id}]
            )
        })
    }
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, "Choose the type", options);
}


I tried to use polling and handle a callback_query event, but it didn't work either
const TelegramApi = require('node-telegram-bot-api');

const BOT_TOKEN = process.env.BOT_TOKEN;
const bot = new TelegramApi(BOT_TOKEN, {polling: true});
// bot.setWebHook(`${process.env.URL}/bot`);

bot.on('callback_query', (query) => {
    console.log(query);
})
bot.on('message', msg => {
    console.log(msg);
})

module.exports = bot;

Again, updates with messages are recieved, but callback_query is never fired

I'm wondering if you're even getting the callback_query updates. Can you please update the LongPolling example with the following code:
const bot = new TelegramBot("TOKEN", {
    polling: {
        params: {
            allowed_updates: [
                "message", "callback_query", // list any other ...
            ]
        }
    }
});

Basically what changed is, we know explicitly request callback_query updates to be sent from Telegram Bot API server.
And you can also do the same while calling the /setWebhook call. Specify the allowed_updates as query parameter or in the JSON body.
Example:
https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/setWebhook?url=<YOUR_URL>&allowed_updates=["message", "callback_query"]

Make sure to replace  with your actual Bot Token, and <YOUR_URL> with your webhook URL. Also, feel free to add any further update types you want to listen to the allowed_updates parameter list.
Hope this helps.
